# JQgrid Dialog not displaying in search operator dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net

why dialog search never show operators drop down(equal-not equal-contains-is in,.....) !?!?

this is my code :

```
 <trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGrid1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="OrderID" Searchable="true">
            </trirand:JQGridColumn>
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Freight" Editable="true" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="OrderDate" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}"
                DataType="Date" Searchable="true" SearchToolBarOperation="IsEqualTo" />
            <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ShipCity" Editable="true" SearchToolBarOperation="Contains"
                Searchable="true" />
        </Columns>
        <ToolBarSettings ShowRefreshButton="true" ShowSearchButton="true" />
        <SearchDialogSettings ValidateInput="false" />
        <SortSettings InitialSortColumn=""></SortSettings>
    </trirand:JQGrid>
```